# How to assign a value to an associative array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an associative array called `$data` and a function called `sendToView()` which is accepting `$email` and `$vehicleid` as parameters. I need to assign those parameters to `$data` array. How can I do that?

Here I have mentioned what I have tried but it is giving *"Trying to get property of non-object"* error. How can i solve that?

```
public function sendToView($email, $vehicleid) {        
    $data['details'] = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'id'    => $vehicleid
    );

 $this->load->view('pages/OfferView',$data);
}
```

offerView.php

```
<?php foreach ($details as $detail) {?>



                        <form name="myform4" action="<?php echo base_url(). 'OfferCtrl/sendEmailToReview/'. $detail->email .'/'. $detail->id ;?> " method="POST">
```

I have done this in offerView.php.Is that error occurs due to this?

Comment: Is the `$data` variable even inside the scope of this function?

Comment: in general this is fine. where do you define `$data` and where/how do you call the function?

Comment: You don't get that error message because of this code. `$data` is an uninitialized variable but PHP is gentle and due to the square brackets it creates an empty array and put it in `$data` before running the assignment. It is, however, a local variable and it disappears as soon as the function returns. Read more about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP.

Comment: write this way you will not get that error.`$data['details'][] = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'id'    => $vehicleid
    );`

Comment: Just change $detail->email to $detail['email'], $details is an array so you need to access its contents via brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function sendToView($email, $vehicleid) {        
   $data['details'] = array();
   $data['details']['email'] = $email;
   $data['details']['id'] = $vehicleid;

 $this->load->view('pages/OfferView',$data); //load it into the view
}
```

when accessing it, you can loop through and push your data back to a variable 
i.e

```
$email = $details['email'];
$id = $details['id'];
```

You can then proceed to use the variables $email and $id in your code . 
Something like this:

```
<form name="myform4" action="<?php echo base_url(). 'OfferCtrl/sendEmailToReview/'. $email .'/'. $>id ;?> " method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

When you just pass an data array can access it through `foreach` loop like this

```
$email = $data['details']['email']; 
$id = $data['details']['id'];
```